# Preprocessor c, [constant or variable]

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have 3 files:

in file1.h I declared:

```
#ifdef SYMBOLE
extern int const my_var;
#else
extern int my_var;
#endif
```

in file file2.c I defined:

```
int my_var;
```

and in file3.c I initialized my_var:

```
my_var = 4;
```

My question is, if I declared `my_var` like this way then `my_var` will be considered constant or variable especially if `SYMBOLE` is defined ?

Comment: Constant variable is a variable. Aside from that, your code is very likely to result in 'multiple definitions'-kind linking errors if `SYMBOLE` isn't defined.

Comment: sorry i forgot the word extern! i will edit my post

Comment: You did not declare the variable in file2 but defined it. The file3 is no valid C code since assignments are allowed only in function. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line in file2.c is not definition, it is a declaration. (unless you initialize it)

So if SYMBOLE is defined, your variable will be conisdered constant and cause a compilation error in file2.c because of conflicting type declaration for variable my_var.